# for loop: truncate string on the right hand side step by step

Tags: regex, bash, for-loop

```
WholeWord="Foo bar sells drinks"
for (( character=0; character<${#WholeWord}; character++ )); do
    echo ${WholeWord:$character}
done
```

Prints out:

```
Foo bar sells drinks
oo bar sells drinks
o bar sells drinks
bar sells drinks
bar sells drinks
ar sells drinks
r sells drinks
sells drinks
sells drinks
ells drinks
lls drinks
ls drinks
s drinks
drinks
drinks
rinks
inks
nks
ks
s
```

Instead of trimming the first letter of every first letters, I would like to trim the last ones, creating the output like this:

```
Foo bar sells drinks
Foo bar sells drink
Foo bar sells drin
Foo bar sells dri
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

WholeWord="Foo bar sells drinks"
for (( character=${#WholeWord}; character>0; --character )); do
    echo ${WholeWord:0:$character}
done
```

What this code does:

Count backward from the size of the whole string to 0, giving that number of characters from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Oh, so THAT's how you subtract.. I was trying to do `character--`

Comment: @TuxForLife `character--` works too as long as it's in the `(())`. `--foo` is an old habit I picked up because it's traditionally a faster op. [More info about prefix vs suffix increment.](http://www.idinews.com/peeves/prefixIncr.html)

Comment: I am sure you probably know, but: You should use `#!/bin/bash` as the she-bang because `sh` does not have such for loops nor "Substring  Expansion".

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this with negative length as 2nd parameter:

```
echo "$WholeWord"
for (( character=1; character<${#WholeWord}; character++ )); do
   echo "${WholeWord:0: -$character}"
done

Foo bar sells drinks
Foo bar sells drink
Foo bar sells drin
Foo bar sells dri
Foo bar sells dr
Foo bar sells d
Foo bar sells
Foo bar sells
Foo bar sell
Foo bar sel
Foo bar se
Foo bar s
Foo bar
Foo bar
Foo ba
Foo b
Foo
Foo
Fo
F
```

Comment: You may want to link to the reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-parameter-expansion

Comment: Hi Mr. anubhava, thanks for your answer, I will be marking @amphetamachine's answer as the solved answer, simply because his didn't omit the very first line. I wish to use it as part of the loop, thus I will have to go with his method

Answer (score 3):

For almost any shell use this script.
Just chop off one char of the string each time after printing it:

```
#!/bin/sh
WholeWord="Foo bar sells drinks"
foo="$WholeWord"

while [ "$foo" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$foo"
    foo="${foo%?}"
done
```

Or, if you must use `Substring Expansion` then make the length go down to 1 on each step:

```
WholeWord="Foo bar sells drinks"

for (( character=${#WholeWord}; character>0; character-- )); do
    printf '%s\n' "${WholeWord:0:$character}"
done
```

---

```
Foo bar sells drinks
Foo bar sells drink
Foo bar sells drin
Foo bar sells dri
Foo bar sells dr
Foo bar sells d
Foo bar sells 
Foo bar sells
Foo bar sell
Foo bar sel
Foo bar se
Foo bar s
Foo bar 
Foo bar
Foo ba
Foo b
Foo 
Foo
Fo
F
```

Answer (score 1):

without counting chars

```
$ foo="Foo bar sells drinks"
$ while [[ ! -z $foo ]]; do echo $foo; foo=$(sed 's/.$//' <<< $foo); done

Foo bar sells drinks
Foo bar sells drink
Foo bar sells drin
Foo bar sells dri
Foo bar sells dr
Foo bar sells d
Foo bar sells
Foo bar sell
Foo bar sel
Foo bar se
Foo bar s
Foo bar
Foo ba
Foo b
Foo
Fo
F
```

Comment: As binaryZebra demonstrated, there's no reason to call out to sed for each char, the shell's builtin parameter expansion can handle it.